# C++/Doxygen: Is it possible to document a struct initialization to expose the actual values?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's say I have a global instance of a struct s/w in my code. I need the user to be capable of knowing the values used for the struct initialization. is there a way to do this?

```
/*!
    \brief I want the values of this instance of the struct to be exposed via doxygen not the struct itself.
    */
    const myStruct xyz = {
    1, ///< This value decides..
    2, ///< bla
    3  ///< even more bla
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK no. Can't you explain the value in the variable's documentation directly? And what each value decides should be documented in the constructor IMHO...

Comment: I haven't seen a way to do it either, I'm using @snippet and put the relevant tags around the initializers. Output is like code / preformatted test, so probably not 100% like would like it but no double / missing parts.

Comment: There is no CTOR since these instances are global. They are used as parameters and hence, changes are likely. And whoever changes them wants as little as possible effort regarding documentation.

Comment: @albert This could be an option, although I didn't get it working ad hoc. I keep trying thanks so far!

Comment: I solved it using \dontinclude command https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmddontinclude